# Building ATL projects

Tags: c++, atl

I'm trying to build an ATL based project on a build server. For that I have installed latest Windows SDK, however getting an error:

"Cannot open include file: 'atlbase.h': No such file or directory".

I have checked and to my surprise SDK does not contain ATL anymore. I cannot neither refactor ATL out on this stage nor install a VS on the build server. What would be an extra set up to build ATL?

Comment: You can't install VS on a build server? That seems highly illogical. The paid versions of VS should include ATL.

Comment: It is really an awful idea to install IDEs on build servers. I find it quite logical. However people with windows background may have a different opinion.

Comment: I was unaware that you could even install the compiler without the IDE. To me having a consistent build environment between the server and the developer workstations would be critical, even if you never use the IDE.

Comment: You can. Our pure .NET build environments have only .NET 4 installed at all (msbuild is a part of runtime). For C++ build servers we only use SDK as it helps to understands what are the end user dependencies better.

Comment: I can't believe someone has put +1 to adding VS on build servers.

Comment: Not only you should install VS on build server to - as Mark said - have proper build environment, but you also have to since you won't have ATL headers available otherwise (BTW Windows SDK never contained ATL, at least within last 10 years).

Comment: Can I rephrase? You should only install VS on one build server if you use legacy API which cannot be compiled in normal environment. Isolate that build server and point out to everyone they shouldn't use it for regular builds. Otherwise you will run in many deployment problems and your project will probably fail to deliver.

Answer (score 1):

ATL / MFC is installed by VS so, if you can't install VS, perhaps you could install it somewhere then take the headers, libs and DLLs and install them manually on your build server. Bit messy but it should work.

Comment: probably I could do that once as a custom NuGet package

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem lately. If you're using an Express edition of Microsoft Visual Studio, you can't use ATL. I know it sounds illogical, but I guess there's no way of doing that. Some MSDN guy told me that in the license file of Microsoft Visual Studio Express Editions, there's a line about that. ATL is not free, so you have to buy it, or use Pro editions of Microsoft Visual Studio.

In Microsoft Driver Dev Kit, there's ATL classes, but they give weird linking errors. So, I guess you have to use Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Professional, or 2010 Professional.

I can help you more if there are more errors/problems about setting up ATL I guess.

Take care.